# Reverse geocoding for multiple coordinates using ArcGIS API

Tags: geocoding, arcgis-python-api, reverse-geocoding

My code is generating coordinates `(Lat, Lon)` of 1000 houses. Now I want to reverse these 1000 coordinates to get the full address. The code is:

```py
import pprint
from arcgis.geocoding import reverse_geocode

Houses = [0]*(1000)
Houses[0], Houses[1] = (143.5689855, -38.328956999999996), (143.5692555, -38.328993)

for i in range(2, 1000):
    latitude_diff = Houses[i-1][0] - Houses[i-2][0]
    longitude_diff= Houses[i-1][1] - Houses[i-2][1]
    temp = (Houses[i-1][0]+latitude_diff, Houses[i-1][1]+longitude_diff)

    Houses[i] = temp

pprint.pprint(Houses)
```

I tried `reverse_geocode()` from [ArcGIS API for Python](https://developers.arcgis.com/python/guide/reverse-geocoding/) but it only converts single coordinate like below:

```py
results = reverse_geocode([143.5689855, -38.328956999999996])
```

How can I reverse the coordinates of 1000 houses into full addresses?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your error was probably similar to this one

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/test.py", line 24, in <module>
    results = reverse_geocode(pt)
  File "C:\...\_functions.py", line 1054, in reverse_geocode
    geocoder = arcgis.env.active_gis._tools.geocoders[0]
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_tools'
```

It is most likely because of the credentials that have to be specified `gis = GIS("http://www.arcgis.com", "username", "password")`.

Otherwise, I would doubt that ArcGIS libraries could be deployed without [a license](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/guide/licensing/).

So, the final code will look as follows (including comments)

```py
import csv
from arcgis.gis import GIS
from arcgis.geometry import Geometry
from arcgis.geocoding import reverse_geocode


gis = GIS("http://www.arcgis.com", "***", "***")

houses = []
houses.append((143.5689855, -38.328956999999996))
houses.append((143.5692555, -38.328993000000000))

lat_diff = houses[1][0] - houses[0][0]
lon_diff = houses[1][1] - houses[0][1]

i = 1
while i <= 5:
    houses.append((houses[i][0] + lat_diff, houses[i][1] + lon_diff))
    i = i + 1

result = []

for x, y in houses:
    pt = Geometry({
        "x": float(x),
        "y": float(y),
        "spatialReference": {
            "wkid": 4326
        }
    })
    try:
        result.append(reverse_geocode(pt))
    except:
        pass

i = 0
result_to_csv = []

for item in result:
    i += 1
    result_item = {
        'id': i,
        'address': item['address']['LongLabel'],
        'lat': round(item['location']['x'],6),
        'lon': round(item['location']['y'],6)
    }
    result_to_csv.append(result_item)

keys = result_to_csv[0].keys()

with open('output.csv', 'w', encoding='utf8', newline='') as output_file:
    dict_writer = csv.DictWriter(output_file, keys, delimiter=';', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE, lineterminator='\r')
    dict_writer.writeheader()
    dict_writer.writerows(result_to_csv)
```

The output CSV-file

[image: output]

when `1.000` of houses have to be geocoded then adjust this part `while i < 999`.

Comment: @Thank you for great results. Can we save the above results to `.CSV`?. For instance: The first column give us address and 2nd column give us latitude,Latitude.